# What does SAML error code 101 means in ManageEngine Service Desk Plus?

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, saml, saml-2.0, keycloak-services

I am integrating my Keycloak application as a IDP for ManageEngine Service Desk Plus using SAML certification, Ive configured it using the metadata file generated by the ManageEngine Client, ive validated the SAML Request file and the Response file, both are correct using the same NameID Format, also the Keycloak`s Event tabs shows my Login attemps as successfull, but the ManageEngine Login still shows me "SAML error code 101"

PS: The Status tag on the Response XML also is Successfull

So Far Ive had 3 problems:

1 - Keycloak Returns Invalid Requester
Solved by disabling the slient signature on keycloak

2- SAML authentication failed with error code 37 on ManageEngine Login (which apperantelly means that i have multiple attributes with the same Name om my SAML)
https://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/saml-authentication-error-codes.html
Solved by changing  a client roles mapper that generatedall the roles with the same attribute name

3 - SAML authentication failed with error code 101
Which is the error that i am stuck on, and i have not fount anything about this